# Matplotlib axis label: \theta does not work \Theta does

Tags: matplotlib, axis-labels

I have a weird behaviour in matplotlib. Using the following I get a nice and shiny big theta. As soon as I use `\theta` instead of `\Theta` I get

> heta

as an axis label

```
plt.figure(**pd.figpropsHP)
line=pd.lineCycler()
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(length-1):
        velocity[i,j]=(velocity[i,j+1]-velocity[i,j])*1000 #multiplied with sampling rate
    plt.plot(velocity[i,startstop[0]:startstop[1]],**next(line))  
        #plt.show(pPosition)
plt.xlabel("t[ms]")    
plt.ylabel("$\dot{\Theta}$[deg/s]")  
plt.ylim(-3000,-3000+yrangeV)
plt.annotate('30ms',fontsize='9', xy=(30, -1000),xytext=(40, -1000),verticalalignment='center',arrowprops=myarrow)
plt.annotate('8ms',fontsize='9', xy=(8, -1700),xytext=(40, -1700),verticalalignment='center',arrowprops=myarrow)
plt.axvline(x=span2Stop,lw='0.3',c='0.5')
plt.axvspan(spanStart, spanStop, facecolor='0.9', alpha=1,edgecolor='0.9',lw=0)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig(imagePath + "collisionTestbedVmot.pdf")
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? I sadly do not have any time to start fancy stuff (latex integration etc.). Can I use an utf8 character instead? How do I get one?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If you specify that the string is raw text (a `r` before the quotation mark), it works. Like this:

```
plt.ylabel(r"$\dot{\Theta}$[deg/s]")
```

The reason you got an unexpected result is that `\t` means a tab. So if you type `\theta`, it is parsed as `\t` and following `heta`. If you specify it a a raw string, backslashes and python escapes will not be treated.

If you don't use raw strings, you have to escape the backslash (`\\`) so python treats it as a backslash and not as a tab symbol (so as \theta and not as \t and heta). That's why `\\theta` did the job. To avoid always have to write double backslashes, use raw strings when using latex, since it uses backslashes a lot for special characters.

Answer (score 10):

using `\\theta` did the job. Anyway this is really a strange behaviour that, in my eyes, should be fixed to do it or not no matter whether it is `\theta` or `\Theta`. Any thoughts about that?

Comment: your reply is based of misunderstanding strings in python. When you write '\\t' you escape the slash.  If you don't escape the '\' python interprets your string as it should include a tab (to which the sign is \t). That is exactly why get 'heta' and a tab in front of it. The solution suggest by joris is also possible, since it tells python to pass a raw string to latex and not interpret it.